# Windows XP, write protect a partition on non-system disk

Tags: windows, windows-xp, hard-drive, partitioning, write-protect

I need to be able to disable writing to disk, on a drive in Windows XP. I don't see this on Google searches...?

To be more clear, I'm not looking to protect the C:, but rather another HD called F:.
In fact, I'd like to make another partition G: on the non-system drive for additional backups of new data and write protect that as well.

This is for a friend with very limited resources and old computer.
I did make him a non-admin account for everyday use so that he would be less likely 
to do bad things to his machine. This gentlemen is not computer savy and is in general hard 
on systems.

EDIT: As Dave pointed out, I do not really want to write-protect a new partition G: which would be for backups...I'll simply change the root folder's permissions.

Comment: finally found diskpart and some limited instructions...not sure how to set the read-only flag but it's a start...btw, I'm planning on using parted-magic for some chores, can I use PM to set the flag..?

Comment: Sorry, you want to make your backup drive write protected? How would you back up to your drive?

Comment: This can be done by setting the permissions on a non-root folder to not allow the `User` group the ability to write to the folder.